# Using environment variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How are environment variables different in Ruby from other languages?  How are they used differently than other Ruby variables?  Any tips or warnings regarding envionment variables in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

You access the environment variables through ENV hash, e.g. ENV['PATH']. It's all the same in every language.